# RubyMine JRuby-1.7.0 Breakpoint from Unit Test or Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, jruby, rubymine, jrubyonrails

My environment:

JRuby-1.7.0

Rails 3.0.0

RubyMine 2016.1.2

I can set a breakpoint successfully when launching the full webapp using rails s:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0/bin/jruby --1.9 -X+O -J-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF -J-Djruby.debug.fullTrace=true -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)        /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 55357 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 47578 -- /home/user/dev/share/app/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
```

but when I run a script or a simple test with:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0/bin/jruby --1.9 -X+O -J-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF -J-Djruby.debug.fullTrace=true -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)        /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 41191 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 48760 -- /home/user/dev/share/app/test/standalone/exercise_some_code.rb
```

or:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.0/bin/jruby --1.9 -X+O -J-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF -J-Djruby.debug.fullTrace=true -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 40324 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 39000 -- /home/user/dev/share/app/test/unit/some_test.rb --name=test_incident_date
```

The breakpoint is ignored. Any thoughts? I am out of ideas here.

Installed gems:

> abstract (1.0.0) actionmailer (3.0.0, 2.3.4) actionpack (3.0.0, 2.3.4)
>   activemodel (3.0.0) activerecord (3.0.0, 2.3.4)
>   activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.1.3) activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
>   (1.1.3) activeresource (3.0.0, 2.3.4) activesupport (3.0.0, 2.3.4)
>   acts_as_list (0.7.4) arel (1.0.1) builder (2.1.2) bundler (1.0.22)
>   bundler-unload (1.0.2) columnize (0.9.0) dbi (0.4.5)
>   debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8) deprecated (2.0.1) erubis (2.6.6)
>   executable-hooks (1.3.2) gem-wrappers (1.2.7) i18n (0.7.0, 0.4.2)
>   jdbc-mysql (5.1.22) jruby-launcher (1.1.1 java) jruby-openssl (0.9.17
>   java) json (1.8.3 java) linecache (1.3.1 java) mail (2.2.20)
>   mime-types (1.25.1) minitest (5.9.0) net-ldap (0.11) polyglot (0.3.5)
>   power_assert (0.3.0) rack (1.2.8, 1.0.1) rack-mount (0.6.14) rack-test
>   (0.5.7) rails (3.0.0, 2.3.4) railties (3.0.0) rake (11.2.2, 0.9.2.2)
>   ruby-debug (0.10.6) ruby-debug-base (0.10.6 java) ruby-debug-ide
>   (0.6.1.beta2) rubygems-bundler (1.4.4) rvm (1.11.3.9) test-unit
>   (3.2.0) thor (0.14.6) thread_safe (0.3.5 java) treetop (1.4.15) tzinfo
>   (1.2.2, 0.3.50) will_paginate (3.1.0)